# how can i use html5 and jquery in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I want to use my original html in node.js

This is simple **hsh.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> How to Say Hello </title>
    <link type="text/css" href="./sys/lib/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link type="text/css" href="./sys/lib/css/jquery-ui.1.10.3.smoothness.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./sys/lib/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./sys/lib/scripts/jquery-ui.1.10.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./sys/lib/scripts/myhello.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#sayDate" ).datepicker();
    });

    function resetHello()
    {
        document.getElementById("hello").value = "";
        document.getElementById("sayDate").value = "";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="syaHello">
        How to say hello in your contry?<br>
        <input type="text" id="hello" value="">
        <INPUT id=sayDate style="WIDTH: 100px" name=sayTime>
    </form>
    <div class="docBtn_list">
        <input type="button" value="View Hello" onclick="javascript:howHello();" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetHello();" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**myhello.js**

```
function howHello()
{
    alert(document.getElementById("hello").value + " " + 
          document.getElementById("sayDate").value);
}
```

and **nodeSev.js**

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('./hsh.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(3000);
});
```

But this is not working about jquery and howHello java script.

I don't want change html and js too much and don't use **express** package.

Comment: One problem, is that you will write back the html for every request including those for your static assets (`.js`, `.css`, etc). You need to implement your own routing logic for that or use a framework.

Comment: The question is wrong. It has nothing to do with jQuery. It should read "How can I serve static files?". And those guys who really want to use jQuery server-side, have a look at [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Comment: The HTML5 doctype is simply `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Just start using Express anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering your question...

Your question aims at serving static web content.

You should install 'express' (a node module based on famous 'connect', which can be used for this as well but lacks other features) and configure it to serve your file from a static directory:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

/* configure your static directory */
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
});

/* on request, send index.html */
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Now that you have `express` installed, take a look at [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/).

You can then process received requests and dynamically serve content. That's state of the art - serving pre-coded html is 90's-style.